# Scraping values of a graph from Fred Economics website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to scrape the data from the graph using BeautifulSoup Library I am new to web scrapping and I am not able to locate the values of the graph in the HTML source page

website: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PCU33633363
Graph : Index Dec 2003 = 100

I want to scrape the data for 1 year i.e. it should be like this Jul 2021 = 118.357 August 2021 = 198.986. I Want this for July 2021 till July 2022. I am able to locate the HTML tag and class of months in the source code but I am not able to locate the values which are on the graph.

This is the code that I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PCU33633363"
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('g', class_="highcharts-axis-labels")

with open('trading.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Months', 'Value']
    thewriter.writerow(header)
 
for list in lists:
    # these values should be only for one year from Jul 2021 - Jul 2022
    # Here tspan is coming inside the text tage and in both tags classes are not mentioned 
    months = list.find('tspan', class_="").text.replace('\n', '') 
    values = # Dont know how to locate it in the hrml source code
    
    
    data = [months, location]
    thewriter.writerow(values)
```

My question is how can I get the month's name from July 2021 to July 2022 along with the values which are mentioned on the Graph? I want the final output to be stored in an excel file. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That information is being pulled dynamically in page, via XHR calls (so requests(bs4 cannot see the information): review the Dev Tools - Network tab, and you will see them. There is a GET call, pulling some data - that is easy to access with requests, is that what you're looking for? If not, there are a few POST calls, with big payloads - are those returning what you need?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire What I want is when I hover over the graph bar there is only value against each month coming which I guess is the average of the whole month. I want to receive that single value against its respective month. so the final output will be only 12 values (July 2021 - July 2022) from that graph. I am a beginner with web scrapping I don't know much about getting dynamic data. can you post the solution so I can the idea at least? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I commented: That information is being pulled dynamically in page, via XHR calls (so requests(bs4 cannot see the information): review the Dev Tools - Network tab, and you will see them. The following code will post a request with the relevant dates you're looking after, and will return a dataframe unfortunately containing only this year's data. You will need to investigate further, and check the other XHR requests (and their respective headers), but this should put you on the right track:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'accept': 'application/json',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}


payload = '{"hostName":"fred.stlouisfed.org","series":[],"chart":{"labels":{"title":"Producer Price Index by Industry: Motor Vehicle Parts Manufacturing","subtitle":"Source: U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics","left_axis":"Index Dec 2003=100","right_axis":"","bottom_axis":"","bubble-size_axis":"","footer":"2022 fred.stlouisfed.org"},"cosd":"2021-07-01","coed":"2022-06-01","min_date":"2003-12-01","max_date":"2022-06-01","frequency":"Monthly","width":"748","height":450,"drp":0,"stacking":null,"txtcolor":"#444444","mode":"fred","ts":"12","tts":"12","fo":"open sans","x_scale":"time","trc":0,"nt":0,"thu":0,"bgcolor":"#e1e9f0","graph_bgcolor":"#ffffff","showLegend":"yes","showAxisTitles":"yes","zoomType":"x","showTooltip":"yes","chartType":"line","recession_bars":"on","showNavigator":"true","available_chart_types":["line","area","column","scatter","pie","bubble"],"log_scales":{"left":false,"right":false,"bottom":false,"bubble-size":false},"available_stacking":["normal","percent"],"legacy_url":"bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=1168&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=PCU33633363&scale=left&cosd=2003-12-01&coed=2022-06-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Monthly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2020-02-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2022-07-14&revision_date=2022-07-14&nd=2003-12-01","piedate":null,"lastModified":"Thu, 14 Jul 2022 12:56:20 GMT","obsFetch":true,"data_min":1070258400000,"data_max":1654059600000,"data_num_obs":223},"xAxis":{},"yAxis":{},"seriesObjects":[{"type":"time-series","line_index":1,"legendIndex":1,"title":"Producer Price Index by Industry: Motor Vehicle Parts Manufacturing","hide_marks":true,"available_formula_transformations":{"lin":{"full":"","short":""},"chg":{"full":"Change","short":"Chg."},"ch1":{"full":"Change from Year Ago","short":"Chg. from Yr. Ago"},"pch":{"full":"Percent Change","short":"% Chg."},"pc1":{"full":"Percent Change from Year Ago","short":"% Chg. from Yr. Ago"},"pca":{"full":"Compounded Annual Rate of Change","short":"Comp. Annual Rate of Chg."},"cch":{"full":"Continuously Compounded Rate of Change","short":"Cont. Comp. Rate of Chg."},"cca":{"full":"Continuously Compounded Annual Rate of Change","short":"Cont. Comp. Annual Rate of Chg."},"log":{"full":"Natural Log","short":"Log"},"nbd":{"full":"Index (Scale value to 100 for chosen period)","short":"Index"}},"line_color":"#4572a7","line_style":"solid","lw":2,"mark_type":"none","mw":3,"scale":"left","decimal_places":"3","frequency":"Monthly","fq":"Monthly","available_colors":{"1":"#4572A7","2":"#AA4643","3":"#89A54E","4":"#80699B","5":"#3D96AE","6":"#DB843D","7":"#92A8CD","8":"#A47D7C","9":"#B5CA92","10":"#91e8e1","11":"#8d4653","12":"#8085e8"},"available_fams":{"Average":"avg","Sum":"sum","End of Period":"eop"},"fam":"avg","available_fqs":["Monthly","Quarterly","Semiannual","Annual"],"fml":"a","fgst":"lin","fgsnd":"2020-02-01","all_fred_series_have_same_frequency":true,"has_fred_series_with_nbd_transformation":false,"cosd":"2021-07-01","coed":"2022-06-01","min_date":"2003-12-01","max_date":"2022-06-01","year_range":19,"ost":-99999,"oet":99999,"available_mmas":[0,1,2],"mma":0,"graph_series_ids":["PCU33633363"],"series_objects":{"a":{"series_id":"PCU33633363","title":"Producer Price Index by Industry: Motor Vehicle Parts Manufacturing","season":"Not Seasonally Adjusted","season_short":"NSA","frequency":"Monthly","frequency_short":"M","units":"Index Dec 2003=100","units_short":"Index Dec 2003=100","keywords":" ","notes":"","all_obs_transformations":{"lin":"Index Dec 2003=100","cap":"Index Dec 2003=100 per Capita","chg":"Change, Index Dec 2003=100","ch1":"Change from Year Ago, Index Dec 2003=100","pch":"Percent Change","pc1":"Percent Change from Year Ago","pca":"Compounded Annual Rate of Change","cch":"Continuously Compounded Rate of Change","cca":"Continuously Compounded Annual Rate of Change"},"abbreviated_all_obs_transformations":{"lin":"Levels","cap":"Levels per Capita","chg":"Chg.","ch1":"Chg. from Yr. Ago","pch":"% Chg.","pc1":"% Chg. from Yr. Ago","pca":"Comp. Annual Rate of Chg.","cch":"Cont. Comp. Rate of Chg.","cca":"Cont. Comp. Annual Rate of Chg.","log":"Log"},"obs_transformations":{"lin":"Index Dec 2003=100","chg":"Change, Index Dec 2003=100","ch1":"Change from Year Ago, Index Dec 2003=100","pch":"Percent Change","pc1":"Percent Change from Year Ago","pca":"Compounded Annual Rate of Change","cch":"Continuously Compounded Rate of Change","cca":"Continuously Compounded Annual Rate of Change"},"valid_start_date":"2022-07-14","valid_end_date":"2022-07-14","vintage_date":"2022-07-14","available_revision_dates":["2022-07-14"],"revision_date":"2022-07-14","relative_vintage":null,"nd":"2003-12-01","step_line":"f","transformation":"lin","available_units":{"lin":"Index Dec 2003=100","chg":"Change, Index Dec 2003=100","ch1":"Change from Year Ago, Index Dec 2003=100","pch":"Percent Change","pc1":"Percent Change from Year Ago","pca":"Compounded Annual Rate of Change","cch":"Continuously Compounded Rate of Change","cca":"Continuously Compounded Annual Rate of Change"},"min_valid_start_date":"2022-07-14","max_valid_start_date":null,"min_obs_start_date":"2003-12-01","max_obs_start_date":"2022-06-01","last_updated":"2022-07-14 07:56:20-05"}},"lsv":null,"lev":null,"observation_grouping_approximation":"close","chart_key":"ff6a10b352b27f6f7642cd95d9695ef2"}],"fredLogo":{"width":105,"height":22,"image":"https://fred.stlouisfed.org/images/fredgraph-logo-2x.png"},"container":{"width":748,"height":450},"defaultFontSize":12,"defaultMaxTicks":10,"showNavigator":true,"showCredits":true,"userNotices":[],"dataParams":{},"dataUrl":"https://fred-sa.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-data.php","graphBreakpointWidth":400,"observations":{},"axisTitleHeight":300,"titleWidth":583,"alignTicks":true,"borderRadius":0,"recessionBars":"on","spacingBottom":15,"spacingTop":50,"spacingRight":20,"zoomType":"x","style":{"fontFamily":"Open Sans","color":"color: rgb(68, 68, 68)"},"chartTypes":{"line":"LINE","area":"AREA","column":"BAR","scatter":"PLOT","pie":"SEGMENT"},"chartTypeIcons":{"line":"fa-chart-line","area":"fa-chart-area","column":"fa-chart-bar","pie":"fa-chart-pie","scatter":""}}'

url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/metadata/'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
# print(r.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
# print(soup)
dfs = pd.read_html(str(soup))
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

This will return a dataframe (which you may want to clean up):

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jun 2022: </td>\n | 123.658</td>\n | </td>\n </tr>\n |
| 1 | May 2022: </td>\n | 123.343</td>\n | </td>\n </tr>\n |
| 2 | Apr 2022: </td>\n | 123.075</td>\n | </td>\n </tr>\n |
| 3 | Mar 2022: </td>\n | 122.499</td>\n | </td>\n </tr>\n |
| 4 | Feb 2022: </td>\n | 121.869</td>\n | </td>\n </tr>\n |
| 5 | View All</a></td></tr>\n </table>\n </div>\n </div>\n \n Units:</p>\n Index Dec 2003=100</span>,Not Seasonally Adjusted </span>\n </div>\n\n Frequency:</p>\n \n \n Monthly </span>\n </span>\n </div>\n"} | View All</a></td></tr>\n </table>\n </div>\n </div>\n \n Units:</p>\n Index Dec 2003=100</span>,Not Seasonally Adjusted </span>\n </div>\n\n Frequency:</p>\n \n \n Monthly </span>\n </span>\n </div>\n"} | nan |